# access php Soap Service from .NET

Tags: php, .net, web-services, soap

I have created php soap web service. As I am new to the php with the help of google the following code shows the soap server.

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$server = new SoapServer("http://localhost/api/soap/report.wsdl");
$server->addFunction("testServer");
$server->handle();
```

I am able to access this service using php soap client and is working fine. The code below shows the php soap client.

```
 $client = new SoapClient("http://localhost/api/soap/report.wsdl", array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,'trace' => 1 ));
   $return = $client->__soapCall("testServer",array());
   print_r($return);
```

But when I am trying to access the above php soap web service using .NET unable to access. I was able to add the service refrence to the .NET project but could not instantiate the serive.

Please help.

Comment: How does your code look like for instantiating the .Net side of the service?

Comment: public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyService ms = new MyService(); //          
        }